# Android Application not running on real device if runned stand alone, but running on emulator and device if attached to system (debug mode or run mod)

Tags: android, service, handler, runnable

I am really helpless why my application is behaving like this, and how to figure out what actually is going wrong.

**AIM** :- to run the `service` in the background after the user is logged in(which actually finishes the `login activity` and starts a `service`), and then generating different activites based on some conditions from `service`.

**Issue** :- If i run this application on emulator on debug mode or Run mode then it works fine
if run it on phone using debugging mode by attaching thru cable it works fine again, Problem arises when i detach the cable and launch it from phone it skips all the cnditions and do not generate activities, I can see the service running.

**Tested** :- I have tested it on all possible emulators without any fail. on devices i have tested it on `2.3.6 Gingerbread` and *4.0.4 ICS* and it failed on both the phone

What I am Using :-

```
android:minSdkVersion="8"
android:targetSdkVersion="16"
```

Services
Runnables + Handlers to open activities from service at particular time intervals..

**CODE :-**

**SERVICE.java**

```
public class EgbaService extends Service {

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

    ActivityInstances_VO.setApplication(getApplication());
    ActivityInstances_VO.setContext(getBaseContext());

    new EgbaTimerTask();

}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    Toast.makeText(this, "Service destroyed...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

**TimerTask.java**

```
public class EgbaTimerTask  {

    //private CloseApplicationTask mCloseApplicationTask = null;

    private SQLHelper helper = null;

    public static boolean requestAdvertisementRun =false;
    private boolean requestMaintainApplicationRun =false;

    private long intervalcalculateTimeSpent = 60000;
    private long intervalShowAdvertisements = 0;

    private int TimeSpent = 0 ;

    private Handler handlerShowAdvertisements = new Handler();
    private Handler handlerCalculateTimespent = new Handler();



    Context mycontext;
    Activity myactivity;
    Application myapp;  

    public EgbaTimerTask()
    {
        this.mycontext=ActivityInstances_VO.getContext();
        this.myapp=ActivityInstances_VO.getApplication();
        this.intervalShowAdvertisements=Advertisements_VO.getInterval() * 60000;
        this.requestAdvertisementRun=true;
        this.requestMaintainApplicationRun=true;
        initializeDatabase();
        startTimerTask();

    }

    private void initializeDatabase() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        helper=new SQLHelper(mycontext);

        try{
            helper.createDataBase();
        }catch (IOException ioe) {
            throw new Error("Unable To Create Database");
        }
        try{
             helper.openDataBase();
        }catch (SQLException sqle) {
            throw sqle;
        }
    }


    public void startTimerTask()
    {
        handlerCalculateTimespent.postDelayed(runnablehandlerCalculateTimespent, intervalcalculateTimeSpent);
        handlerShowAdvertisements.postDelayed(runnableShowAdvertisements, intervalShowAdvertisements);
    }

    private Runnable runnableShowAdvertisements = new Runnable() {
       @Override
       public void run() {
          /* do what you need to do */
           //android.os.Debug.waitForDebugger();

           if(requestAdvertisementRun)
           {


           ShowAdvertisementActivity();
          /* and here comes the "trick" */

            handlerShowAdvertisements.postDelayed(this, intervalShowAdvertisements);
            //Log.i("Who's Running", "Running ShowAdvertisement");

           }
            /* if(i >= 4)
             {   

                 Log.i("Value of i inside check", String.valueOf(i));                 
                 handlerShowAdvertisements.removeCallbacks(runnableShowAdvertisements);
             }*/

       }
    };

    private Runnable runnablehandlerCalculateTimespent = new Runnable() {
           @Override
           public void run() {
              /* do what you need to do */
              /* and here comes the "trick" */

               if(requestMaintainApplicationRun)
               {               

                handlerShowAdvertisements.postDelayed(this, intervalcalculateTimeSpent);
                Log.i("Who's Running", "Calculating Time Spent by User"+String.valueOf(TimeSpent));
                TimeSpent++;
                //android.os.Debug.waitForDebugger();
                if(Registration_VO.getaccount_life()- TimeSpent == 5)
                {
                    Intent i=new Intent(mycontext,NotifyExpirationActivity.class);
                    i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                    myapp.startActivity(i);
                    requestAdvertisementRun=false;
                }

                if(Registration_VO.getaccount_life()- TimeSpent == 3)
                {
                    Intent i=new Intent(mycontext,NotifyExpirationActivity.class);
                    i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                    myapp.startActivity(i);
                }
                //android.os.Debug.waitForDebugger();
                if(Registration_VO.getaccount_life()- TimeSpent == 0)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        boolean ifSubmitted= false;
                        //check for admin authentication
                        helper.updateUserAccountLifeLeft(Registration_VO.getphoneNo(),0);


                        InternetControl.DisableInternet();
                        stopServicefunction();

                        requestAdvertisementRun=false;
                        requestMaintainApplicationRun=false;
                        handlerShowAdvertisements.removeCallbacks(runnableShowAdvertisements); 
                        handlerCalculateTimespent.removeCallbacks(runnablehandlerCalculateTimespent);


                    }
                    catch(SQLException e)
                    {
                        Log.e("EgbaTimerTask", e.toString());
                    }

                }
               }
           }
        };

        public void stopServicefunction()
        {
            Intent serviceIntent = new Intent();
            serviceIntent.setClass(mycontext, EgbaService.class);
            myapp.stopService(serviceIntent);
        }   


    public void ShowAdvertisementActivity()
    {
        Intent dialogIntent = new Intent(mycontext, ShowAdvertisementActivity.class);
        dialogIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        myapp.startActivity(dialogIntent);

    }
```

**Notes**

- runnable is running after 1 minute.
- There are two runnables in this class, both opening different activities depending upon the condition
- service initiates timertask to do all the required things

Comment: Just wondering, how do you know that it isn't running?

Comment: I can see the service running in Settings -> Apps -> Running..

Comment: Then you should add some Log info and check it with a logcat from the device. Its hard to know why isn't running if you are not checking where your service is.

Comment: That the issue, for checking logcat i have to attach the device thru data cable to my system. I had tried that too then it works the way it should work.

Comment: You can have logcat with terminal emulator app, or logcat apps from playstore